# How to play MediaElement only once in Timespan?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

How to start mediaElement only once in given Timespan. Now it opens mediaElement every  second after Button_Click.
I know how to do that in Button_Click, but I need Dispatcher, because of the rest of the code.
It is Windows Store app.

Thanks

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    DispatcherTimer dt2 = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        dt2.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(dt2_Tick);
        dt2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        mediaElement.Stop();

    }

    private void dt2_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
     var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
     var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day, 12, 0, 0);
     TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0);
     TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0); 

    if(IsTimeOfDayBetween(date, start,  end)==true )
    {
         mediaElement.Start();
    }

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        dt2.Start();

    }



    static public bool IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime time,
                                  TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    {
        if (end == start)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (end < start)
        {
            return time.TimeOfDay <= end ||
                time.TimeOfDay >= start;
        }
        else
        {
            return time.TimeOfDay >= start &&
                time.TimeOfDay <= end;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611.aspx) package. It lets you treat events as data sequences and comes with a lot of built in support for event throttling. Specifically, check out [Buffer](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Buffer) method.

From [introtorx](http://www.introtorx.com/):

> You can temporarily withhold a specified number of elements, stash away all the values for a given time span, or use a combination of both count and time.